# Is there a package/library that supports nesting dragable elements into other dragrable elements?

Tags: javascript

Is there a package/library, similar to Gridster or Gridstack, that allows me to take a dragable element and drag it into other dragable element, so they would form parent-child relationship.
I want to support this drag and drop functionality for n amount of levels.

I would like to a have something as in this example, but I need the nesting too: https://tiberiuzuld.github.io/angular-gridster2/

To give another example - I'm looking for a package/library that combines these two functionalities:

1. https://gridstackjs.com/demo/two.html#
2. https://gridstackjs.com/demo/nested.html#

With one of them, I'm able to nest grids, with the other one, I'm able to move elements between grids